# How to set a gnuplot graph key outside the graph borders'?

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot in conjunction with cairolatex to produce my graphs and save them as `.tex` files, which I can easily embed in a LateX report using `\input`. However, I'm running into some problems when it comes to setting the key. Since key overlaps the data points, I used `set key at x, y` in order to give it a little offset, as such:

[image]

In the picture to the left, I tried to shift the key up, but it leaves the screen for some reason, as if there was a limit to the avaible room the graph can take up. On the right you can see what happens if a don't do anything. So the solution may be in the gnuplot or on the LateX side, whichever works.

Comment: Check and read `help key` and the options listed there.

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of options to "set key".  The simplest answer to your question is "set key outside", but you may still want to adjust the positioning more explicitly.  In this case gnuplot will make the graph smaller so that there is room beside it for the key.

```
set term cairolatex pdf standalone
set output 'key.tex'
set multiplot layout 2,1
set key
plot for [i=2:8] sin(x/i) title sprintf("$sin(x/%d)$", i)
set key outside
replot
unset multiplot
```

[image]